# SequelizeMockEmptyQueryQueueError: No query results are queued. Unexpected query attempted to be run

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocking, sequelize.js

I have a few chai tests that call functions that should get a result back from my mock db tables, I'm trying to mock my SQL db using `sequalize-mock` so the tests won't fall over. I'm trying to add seed data to the mockDb so the tests can work with them, however, I keep getting this weird error:

`SequelizeMockEmptyQueryQueueError: No query results are queued. Unexpected query attempted to be run`

Any ideas why this happens?

Here is my mock db init which is running before each test.

This is glboally available in SQL Mock file

```js
const SequelizeMock = require("sequelize-mock");
const dbMock = new SequelizeMock({});
```

```js
export const initializeMockDatabase = async () => {
    const GlobalParam = await generateSqlSchema(
        dbMock,
        GLOBAL_PARAMS_SCHEMA,
    );
    

    const globalParamsfilePath = path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        "../mocks/global_params.json",
    );
    const globalParamsData = fs.readFileSync(globalParamsfilePath, "utf8");
    const globalParams = JSON.parse(globalParamsData);

    // Loop through the globalParams object and create records
    for (const key of Object.keys(globalParams)) {
        const globalParam = GlobalParam.build({
            name: key,
            value: globalParams[key as keyof typeof globalParams],
        });
        await globalParam.save();
    }
};
```

```js
const generateSqlSchema = async <T extends object>(
    db: SqlDatabase,
    schema: SyncDataSchema<T>,
) => {
    const schemaName = schema.id;

    let model = db.models[schemaName];

    if (!model) {
        const attributes: any = {};
        for (const property of schema.properties) {
            const attribute: ModelAttributeColumnOptions = {
                type: SyncDataUtils.convertSyncDataType(property.type),
                primaryKey: property.key === schema.keyProperty,
            };
            if (attribute) {
                attributes[property.key] = attribute;
            }
        }
        model = await syncSqlSchema(db, schemaName, attributes);
    }

    return model;
};


const syncSqlSchema = async <
    T extends object,
    M extends Model,
    TCreationAttributes = M["_attributes"],
>(
    database: SqlDatabase,
    modelName: string,
    attributes: ModelAttributes<M, TCreationAttributes>,
    options?: ModelOptions,
): Promise<SqlSchema<T>> => {
    const model = database.define(modelName, attributes, {
        ...options,
        freezeTableName: true,
    });
    await model.sync({
        alter: {
            drop: false,
        },
        
    });
    return model;
};
```

And then in the before:

```js
before(async function () {
    this.timeout(90 * 1000);

    chai.use(spies);
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

    const projectId = MiscConstants.PROJECT_ID.TEST;

    process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT = projectId;
    process.env.LOCAL_PUBSUB = true;

    await Mocks.setup();
    Mocks.enable();

    // Initialize the mock database
    await initializeMockDatabase();

    // Require all pub-subs
    require("firebase-functions").registerFunctions(require("../../index"));

    //await Emulators.setupEmulators();
});
```

And executing queries like:

```js
export const executeSqlQuery = async <T, R = any>(
    query: string,
): Promise<[R[]]> => {
    return attemptSqlOperation(async () => {
        const convertedQuery = convertToPostgres(query);
        //console.log(convertedQuery.replace(/\n/g, " "));
        return (await dbMock.query(convertedQuery)) as any;
    });
};
```

Any ideas? What I'm missing?